# How to get back hosts file after accidental deletion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I made a mistake and accidentally deleted hosts file from my system and cannot figure out how to get back my hosts (/etc/) file, when I do

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It's showing:

> sudo: unable to resolve host SystemName.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I tried editing the hosts file  `sudo vi hosts` and put:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

But to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the issue is resolving the actual hostname of the machine you are on. Check your hostname by running the `hostname` command like this:

```
hostname
```

Or like this:

```
cat /etc/hostname
```

And let’s say your hostname is `SystemName`. Then you would have to add a line to your `/etc/hosts` file like this:

```
127.0.0.1       SystemName
```

So the whole `/etc/hosts` file would look like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       SystemName
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

You could also consolidate those `127.0.0.1` entries like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost SystemName
```

Then the final `/etc/hosts` file would look like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost SystemName
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```